# Separate input and output panels

Tags: powershell

I've just started playing around with PowerShell. I'm following a tutorial from pluralsight. The tutor uses PowerShell ISE and he has 3 panels in it:

1. Script editor
2. Input console
3. Output console

On my Windows 8.1 with PowerShell 4.0 the PowerShell ISE has only 2 panels. Script editor and a standard console for both input and output.

Is there a way to separate it?

Comment: The input and output panels were combined in PowerShell v3. Is there a reason why you need them separated? Whenever the the tutorial refers to the input or output panel, you should be able to just use the combined panel.

Comment: @Rynant there's no 'real' reason. I just liked the idea of a cleaner output. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't separate the console into separate panes in the ISE. In my opinion, the console in the current ISE is better than the way it was in v2. For example, with the separate panes, if your cursor was in the output pane, you could not start typing without moving to the input pane first.

Also, the old ISE output pane wasn't any cleaner; it still displayed the input code along with the resulting output.

If you prefer to have a dedicated spot for input, the [PowerGUI](http://www.powergui.org/) script editor keeps the input prompt at the bottom of the output pane.